# Clearing contents of a range clears content of the entire sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which copies some data into a table on another sheet, but I want it to also clear the original data from its cells after it copies. I have looked online and found the `.clearContents` method which seemed to work, however when I used it to clear a certain range of cells, like this `Worksheets("sheet").range("B4:B10").clearContents` it cleared data outside that range as well.

This is my entire macro:

```
Sub YesTrade()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim currentDate As String

    currentDate = Date
    lastRow = Worksheets("Trades").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date

    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B4").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2)
    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B5").Copy Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3)

    Dim f5 As Double
    Dim f7 As Double
    f5 = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F24").Value
    f7 = Worksheets("Calculator").Range("F17").Value
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = f5
    Worksheets("Trades").Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = f7

    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("B4:B10").ClearContents

End Sub
```

The last line is meant to clear the data in cells B4 to B10 however it instead clears all the contents from the entire B column and the F column.

Comment: `range("B4:B10").clearContents` clears `"B4:B10"`. So no, the code shown does not clear anything else.

Comment: Do you have any event code which could be triggered by this?

Comment: @SJR this is my only macro if that's what you mean. I have not written any other code.

Comment: @BrakNicku you are right, the other cells use B4 in a formula which is why they also get cleared. I am an idiot.